# Why does using floatThead with Angular/TypeScript yield the error Property 'floatThead' does not exist on type 'JQuery<any>'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, dom, npm

I need to use the 3rd party jQuery library https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead.

I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery installed from the command line with NPM. I've installed floatThead with NPM as well.

In my component, I have these imports:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'floatThead';
```

I successfully select the table element like this:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover" #tableElement>

@ViewChild('tableElement')
private tableElement: ElementRef;
```

And by calling floatThead() like this, I get the above error and see no effect on my site

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   $(this.tableElement.nativeElement).floatThead({top: 50});
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why that is?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xlqrkh

Comment: Maybe `floatthead` instead of `floatThead` in import?

Comment: @RazRonen: Tried that already. Does not do the trick :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

floatThead now comes with typescript types, so update to latest version and it should **"just"** work.

https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead/blob/master/dist/jquery.floatThead.d.ts

which in case you were wondering, look like this:

```
interface floatTheadOptions {
    position?: string;
    scrollContainer?: ($table: JQuery) => JQuery;
    responsiveContainer?: ($table: JQuery) => JQuery;
    ariaLabel: ($table: JQuery, $headerCell: JQuery, columnIndex: number) => string;
    headerCellSelector?: string;
    floatTableClass?: string;
    floatContainerClass?: string;
    top?: number;
    bottom?: number;
    zIndex?: number;
    debug?: boolean;
    getSizingRow?: ($table: JQuery, $cols: JQuery, $fthCells: JQuery) => JQuery;
    copyTableClass?: boolean;
    autoReflow?: boolean;
}

interface JQuery {
    floatThead(floatTheadOptions?: floatTheadOptions): JQuery;
    floatThead(action: string): JQuery;
    trigger(action: string): JQuery;
    on(events: string, handler: (event: Event, $floatContainer: JQuery) => void|boolean): JQuery;
    on(events: string, handler: (event: Event, isFloated: boolean, $floatContainer: JQuery) => void|boolean): JQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `import * as floatThead from 'floatthead';`

And, if it's possible, show us this code on stackblitz

Comment: Tried that as well. Does not work for me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xlqrkh

Comment: Hope it'll help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vfhf3l

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first import statement yields "index.d.ts(35, 1): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag." The second import statement yields "Could not find a declaration file for module 'floatthead'". So I'm still stuck.

Comment: For the first error try add: `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true` in `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`

For the second, try to use:
`const floatThead = require('floatthead');`

If it'll not work, then I don't know how to help you :(

Answer (score 0):

It is because there are no types for `floathead`, so even if the script is included, TS does not know that you can call `$(xxx).floathead()`

What you can do is add `jquery` and `floathead` to the `scripts` section of your `angular.json` file and then:

Either add the following line  below your angular imports

```
declare let $: any;
```

Or, if you've already installed jquery types (`@types/jquery`), you can extend the JQuery interface

```
interface JQuery
{
      floathead(options: any): JQuery;
}
```

And then, on top of your component file

```
declare let $: JQuery;
```

Comment: Thanks! But then ```import * as $ from 'jquery';"``` conflicts with ```declare let $: JQuery;```

Comment: Just add JQuery and floattheadnin your angular.json file, and remove the imports from the component file

Comment: Doing that and including  ```declare let $: any;```, I get no errors. But my application is still not affected by the library. How can I test that it have been integrated properly? Without removing ```declare let $: any;```

Comment: I don't know floathead but you should see right away if it works when calling the method?

Comment: Set a breakpoint when you call the method. If it's going through floathead code then the error is somewhere else